# C# HttpWebRequest Content-type not Changing

Tags: c#, .net, json, post, httpwebrequest

In C# i need to POST some data to a web server using HTTP. I keep getting errors returned by the web server and after sniffing throught the data I dound that the problem is that thew Content-type header is still set to "text/html" and isn't getting changed to "application/json; Charset=UTF-8" as in my program. I've tried everything I can think of that might stop it getting changed, but am out of ideas.

Here is the function that is causing problems:

```
private string post(string uri, Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters)
    {
        //Put parameters into long JSON string
        string data = "{";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in parameters)
        {
            if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                data += "\r\n" + item.Key + ": " + "\"" + item.Value + "\"" + ",";
            }
            else if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {
                data += "\r\n" + item.Key + ": " + item.Value + ",";
            }
        }
        data = data.TrimEnd(',');
        data += "\r\n}";

        //Setup web request
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url + uri);
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentLength = data.Length;
        //Ignore false certificates for testing/sniffing
        wr.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        try
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //Send request to server
                dataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
            }
            //Get response from server
            WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The reason i'm getting problems is because the content-type stays as "text/html" regardless of what I set it as.

Thanks in advence.

Comment: Does the web service accept JSON formatted data?

Comment: Yes. The only isuue that i'm getting is that the content type won't change

Comment: Have you tried `"application/json"` instead of `"application/json; charset=UTF-8";`

Comment: Just tried it - same story. Content type stays as 'text/html'

Comment: The `ContentType` property returned by the server (in `response.ContentType`) is the type of the data returned by the server. It has nothing to do with the `ContentType` that you send in the request. If you want the server to return JSON data, then you typically specify that in the query string (or in your POST data). *If the server supports returning JSON data.*

Comment: Also, you say that you keep getting errors returned by the web server. What is the *exact error message*?

Comment: The Content-Type im talking about is my request content-type, not response content-type - I haven't got as far as getting a decent response from the server yet! It is a 403 Fobidden error that is returned by the server. I've run a packet sniffer on the connection and the only difference between a working app and mine is the content-type field.

Comment: Well, I just spent half a day on this one.  Apparently ordering the call mattered on my end.  I noticed that the ContentType property was being reset to null after other properties on the web request were being set.  I moved the ContentType set till LAST before GetRequestStream and it worked.  What a big WOW that order of property setting can alter other properties being set.  SHAMEFUL.

Answer (score 3):

As odd as this might sound, but this worked for me:

```
((WebRequest)httpWebRequest).ContentType =  "application/json";
```

this changes the internal `ContentType` which updates the inherited one.

I am not sure why this works but I would guess it has something to do with the `ContentType` being an abstract property in `WebRequest` and there is some bug or issue in the overridden one in `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 2):

A potential problem is that you're setting the content length based on the length of the string, but that's not necessarily the correct length to send. That is, you have in essence:

```
string data = "whatever goes here."
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var s = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    s.Write(byteData, 0, data.Length);
}
```

This is going to cause a problem if encoding your string to UTF-8 results in more than `data.Length` bytes. That can happen if you have non-ASCII characters (i.e. accented characters, symbols from non-English languages, etc.). So what happens is your entire string isn't sent.

You need to write:

```
string data = "whatever goes here."
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;  // this is the number of bytes you want to send
using (var s = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    s.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}
```

That said, I don't understand why your `ContentType` property isn't being set correctly. I can't say that I've ever seen that happen.

Comment: Changing that does appear to have fixed the problem - no idea why. I've used `Encoding.UTF-8.GetByteCount(data)` to get the byte count instead of creating another variable.